# Modern way to read gamepad input with C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gamepad, evdev

I am interested in reading gamepad input, specifically a gamepad with the layout of a wired xbox 360 controller, with C on a linux machine. I understand that this can be done in a variety of ways, however I was wondering what is the modern method of accomplishing this.
As I understand it, `evdev` is the 'future' while the Joystick API is legacy. Using `libudev` I am able to find attached gamepads and detect when they are connected and disconnected:

```
// skipping setup code ....
char const* val = udev_device_get_property_value(dev, "ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK");
if (val != NULL && strcmp(val, "1") == 0) {
  char const* devfs_path = udev_device_get_devnode(udev_device);
}
// .....
struct udev_device* device = udev_monitor_recieve_device(udev_monitor); 
char const* action = udev_device_get_action(device);
if (strcmp(action, "add") == 0) {
  // .....
}
if (strcmp(action, "remove") == 0) {
  // .....
}
```

The crux of my question lies in the best way to read button presses and axis movement.
Currently, I am unsure whether to use `struct js_event` or `struct input_event`. In truth, I was hoping to be able to do this with the same check for connected and removed gamepads with `libudev`. If this is not possible, which is the most forward-thinking approach?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: dont derefence a pointer before you validated it.

Comment: @wildplasser I agree with you, I was omitting all error checking for brevity.
Looking at SDL source, they use the input_event struct, so I may use that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/joydev/joystick-api.html)

> Newer clients are encouraged to switch to the generic event (evdev) interface.

The specific mappings for a desired controller can be found in [linux input kernel community docs](http://www.infradead.org/~mchehab/kernel_docs_pdf/linux-input.pdf)

Therefore, use `struct input_event`

Comment: Hi, Your link to pdf lead to 403. Can you please consider re-posting ?

Comment: @Nelstaar It is available on the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/)